# Do a custom comparison between Strings of different columns in a Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, compare

I want to use Pandas to do an automated analysis of formal criteria for SW requirements.
One criteria would be, that requirements do not have a lower [ASIL level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_Safety_Integrity_Level#Levels), than the requirements that they are linked to.
I have already condensed the necessary data into a single dataframe similar to this one:

```
data = {"ID": ["req_115", "req_115", "req_624", "req_982", "req_833", "req_833", "req_833", "req_759"],
        "ASIL level": ["QM(D)", "QM(D)", "QM(D)", "ASIL C(D)", "QM", "QM", "QM", "QM"],
        "linked ID": ["arch_932", "arch_218", "arch_350", "arch_975", "arch_546", np.nan, "arch_548", "prj_531"],
        "linked ASIL level": ["ASIL D", "QM", "QM", "ASIL D", np.nan, np.nan, "ASIL D", "QM"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

        ID ASIL level linked ID linked ASIL level
0  req_115      QM(D)  arch_932            ASIL D
1  req_115      QM(D)  arch_218                QM
2  req_624      QM(D)  arch_350                QM
3  req_982  ASIL C(D)  arch_975            ASIL D
4  req_833         QM  arch_546               NaN
5  req_833         QM       NaN               NaN
6  req_833         QM  arch_548            ASIL D
7  req_759         QM   prj_531                QM
```

I am now trying to print out all the rows, where the ASIL level is lower than the ASIL level of the linked id, to have an outcome like this:

```
        ID ASIL level linked ID linked ASIL level
0  req_115      QM(D)  arch_932            ASIL D
1  req_982  ASIL C(D)  arch_975            ASIL D
2  req_833         QM  arch_548            ASIL D
```

I can't compare the columns with `df[df['ASIL level'] < df['linked ASIL level']]` but would need some kind of comparison according to the hierarchy of the ASIL levels, where ASIL D is the highest one and QM the lowest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create a list that contains the correct order and reference the index of each entry:

```py
order_list = [ 'QM', ..., 'ASIL D']

df[df.apply(lambda row: order_list.index(row['ASIL level']) < order_list.index(row['linked ASIL level']), axis=1)]
```

or a bit more readable:

```py
order_list = [ 'QM', ..., 'ASIL D']

def compare(row):
    order_1 = order_list.index(row['ASIL level']) 
    order_2 = order_list.index(row['linked ASIL level'])
    return order_1 < order_2

df[df.apply(compare, axis=1)]
```